# Google Cloud Client libraries for Document AI API's in Laravel hosted on Microsoft Azure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am using [v1 API](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest) to extract table coordinates in a Laravel web app.
But I have to generate tokens after they expire.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://LOCATION-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/processors/PROCESSOR_ID:method
```

What are the Google client libraries or API libraries for the Document AI's v1 API that can be used in Laravel ?

The site is hosted on Microsoft Azure.

Following links may provide some hint->

[Google API's Github](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.163.1/vision/readme)

[Google API's Github IO](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.163.1/vision/readme)

Comment: Well, Google documentation mentions only Java, Node.js and Python client libraries available  for Document AI - for other languages you can use REST. From the question it seems that you are already using REST... So, I am not sure what exactly is the question about? Can you clarify little bit...

Comment: I want to use client libraries in Laravel.

Comment: But you are already using REST library, this is only way to use in this case. Can you post some example code in Lavarel that you want to improve?

Comment: I thought like Python there may be something in PHP (Laravel). That's fine.
I will implementing using REST.

Comment: Here is the information about the PHP Client Library for Document AI https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-document-ai/latest